# Time/date display on menu bar

Tags: system-settings, time, date

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

The system was previously properly configured to display the time/date on the menu bar through System Settings - Date/Time, and the information was displayed properly. Now in the last day or two, for some reason, the information is no longer displayed. When I go to System Settings - Clock everything on the page is greyed out and nothing can be changed.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to cause the information to be displayed as desired and as it was previously done?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that everything is grayed out in the Time and Date Settings is because it need elevated user privileges. All you need to do is click the unlock button on the bottom of the window then put your user password in.

Alternatively you can use `sudo ntpdate time.nist.gov` in the terminal and have the time update that way as well 
[image: Time and date settings]